# which one is better ngx-table vs sync fusion table in angular....?

Tags: angular, syncfusion, ngx-datatable

I want to use datatable in my angular 9 project but having some confusion that which grid is good according to their features ngx-table or sync fusion grid

[ngx datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable)

[sync fusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/datagrid/overview)

please help to choose according to features...?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/

Comment: thanks you dear friend for your time and response, but I have to choose between ngx-table or sync fusion

Comment: I found one link
https://www.npmtrends.com/@swimlane/ngx-datatable-vs-@syncfusion/ej2-ng-grids-vs-datatables.net-vs-bootstrap-table

this is showing that most of the users are using ngx table. it is comparing other plugin also.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings from the Syncfusion support,

We shared our Demo sample browser and Help Documentation for more information, based on your requirement. Please refer to the below Documentation and Demo that will help to implement your requirement.

Demo link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/grid/overview

Help Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/getting-started/?no-cache=1

Please get back to us, if you need further assistance.

Best,

Balaji S.